# How to enable scrolling in tmux panels with mouse wheel?

Tags: linux, tmux

Need to enable scrolling into tmux panels with mouse wheel. How can I get that tips? Can I use it (if its exist of course) with *mouse-select-pane on* option?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/210125/scroll-shell-output-with-mouse-in-tmux

Comment: It is most amusing when i use and mark up questions / answers that are closed as 'off topic'.  It would have been better in this case if the 'off topic question' was made on-topic by either originator or moderator.

Comment: This question is ***NOT ABOUT HARDWARE*** ‍♂️.  It is about scrolling in `tmux`.  The fact that the OP mentioned the hardware used for scrolling does not make it about hardware anymore than questions about text strings are ABOUT KEYBOARDS.

Comment: Doesn't say it's necessarily about hardware.  Says "...hardware AND SOFTWARE...".  This seems like a question about how to configure a piece of software and not via programming, so sure seems off-topic to me.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

#### Origin Answer (deprecated)

Try this:

```
setw -g mode-mouse on
```

It can be used with the `mouse-select-pane on` and `mouse-select-window on` options.

#### Update

After tmux 2.1, `mode-mouse` option is no longer available. You should now use:

```
set -g mouse on
```

to capture mouse event.

Comment: thx, and maybe u know how to enable mouse copy-past opportunity in this mode?

Comment: @mart7ini Do you mean [this problem](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-888724-start-0.html)?

Comment: This does not work via ssh. :(

Comment: How can I alias it to make a shortcut?

Comment: CONFIRM working on OpenBSD 6.6

Comment: Worth to add that you can create a file `~/.tmux.conf` with the `set -g mouse on` content on it to avoid the need to execute the command on each session.

Comment: It worked for me with tmux-2.8, even using an SSH session.

Answer (score 68):

There are some changes for Tmux 2.1

- Mouse-mode has been rewritten.  There's now no longer options for:

  - mouse-resize-pane
  - mouse-select-pane
  - mouse-select-window
  - mode-mouse

  Instead there is just one option:  'mouse' which turns on mouse support
  entirely.

So `set -g mouse on`

Update:

I have to use this script to make scrolling work again:
https://github.com/NHDaly/tmux-scroll-copy-mode

Comment: Wow that is fantastic!  I'm new to tmux and I really liked it as it solved problems with sessions, but the windows / panes metaphors were somewhat painful (eg. `Ctrl-b o` to switch panes was a pain all the time).  Along with the newly discovered https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum things are really starting to look rosey.

Answer (score 15):

From https://blogs.oracle.com/samf/entry/smcup_rmcup_hate

In .tmux.conf:

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

where, for instance, mouse scrolling in vim in tmux scrolls vim, NOT tmux history.
Very beneficial, and VERY different from history scrolling.

Comment: I thought smcup/rmcup had nothing to do with handling mouse scrolling. it has to do with the "alternate screen" functionality, where these folks want to *turn it off* to leave the contents of vim or less on the term so that they can still see it as they type the next command. (my two cents here is I usually have space to open more terminals so I do this sort of thing in parallel terminals -- more often than not I'd rather see my previous commands after exiting from those programs anyway)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I add this to .tmux.conf and source that file, it just causes gibberish characters to appear that the terminal prompt (for whatever program I am in).

Comment: Yes, scrolling works. But on my Ubuntu computer in vim or less scrolling works through tmux history not vim or less as I expect.

Comment: That must be the default behavior. This emulate  keyboard UP and DOWN arrows. Now tmux implement his own way of scrolling (as before with pgUP pgDOWN). This is a regression, it breaks things.

Comment: this works for tmux 2.7 as well

Answer (score 10):

### For Mac OSX 10.9

First Install [SimpleSIMBL](https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL/releases)

Then Install [MouseTerm](https://github.com/brodie/mouseterm)

Add this to your ~/.tmux.conf

```
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-window on
set-window-option -g mode-mouse on
```

For VIM Scrolling add this to your ~/.vimrc

```
set mouse=a
set ttymouse=xterm
```

Notes: see also: [Scrolling inside Vim in Mac's Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727261/scrolling-inside-vim-in-macs-terminal)

Comment: In Linux I got `.tmux.conf:1: invalid option: mouse-select-pane .tmux.conf:1: invalid option: mouse-select-pane` and `.tmux.conf:3: invalid option: mode-mouse` when Tmux starts and then the session works without any change