# How do I set up tmux on a mac so that I can scroll through the tmux buffer cut and paste with the mouse using CMD-C CMV-V in the default Termina?

Tags: macos, tmux

I'd like to set up tmux on a Mac to be as easy to use as possible.

I want Terminal (the default terminal), not iTerm and I want mouse-scrolling to scroll through the tmux buffer and for mouse cursor + CMD-C/CMD-V to copy/paste text as it does for other mac applications.

This question is similar to [Mouse scrolling and selection in terminal with tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398716/mouse-scrolling-and-selection-in-terminal-with-tmux) and [Mouse scrolling and selection in terminal with tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398716/mouse-scrolling-and-selection-in-terminal-with-tmux) but is not the same.