# How to let vim behave on Mac OS X as on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, osx-mountain-lion

Recently I started using a Macbook Pro. Installed is Mountain Lion and so far everything is good. I'm coming from Ubuntu and being pretty much addicted to vim, I can't really stand how Mac Os X is treating vim. ;)

For instance, if I use the mouse in Ubuntu to scroll up, the max I can scroll is the top of the file when a file is open. When I try that in Mac Os X, I scroll straight into the shell history. I'd like the Ubuntu behaviour better, because I find it easier and more logical (even though I know that vim is a 'terminal' application).

Is there anything I can do about this?

I have iTerm2 installed if that helps.

Please note, I'm using the regular Vim, not Macvim of which I read a lot of things also. I prefer to use the original 'vim' because I'm familiar with the keys/commands etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal.app does not support the mouse.

If you want the mouse you can to install [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) which does support the mouse.

In iTerm2: go to Preferences -> Profiles -> (current profile) -> Terminal and Make sure Enable xterm mouse reporting. After you select this you might need to restart iTerm2.

To enable mouse support in vim add the following to your vimrc

```
set mouse=a
```

Comment: How do I need to configure iTerm2? If I scroll up straight after opening a file in vim using iTerm2, I still scroll 'out of' vim into the shell history. I have just added the set mouse=a option to my .vimrc.

Comment: @Sander I don't think you need to configure iTerm2. It should just work.

Comment: Ok, thanks! :) But then unfortunately it doesn't.. I have a fresh install of iTerm2.

Comment: @Sander go to Preferences -> Profiles -> (current profile) -> Terminal -> Make sure Enable xterm mouse reporting is selected

Comment: That is the case, so not sure if iTerm2 supports the behaviour I'm looking for now.. The 'scrolling issue' is still in effect.

Comment: Ah, wait... I think you were right! I have quit iTerm2 once again, and now it does what I am looking for. Thanks a lot, also for sticking with me there.

Answer (score 2):

FDinoff has already dealt with the main part of your question but allow me to tell you a few things about MacVim:

- Like GVim on Linux or on Windows, it's only a GUI built around Vim. You can use the features provided by the GUI (menus, dialogs, wider color palette...) but you are not forced to as *it doesn't change Vim's behavior*. You have the same commands and everything as in CLI Vim.
- It's a more complete and up-to-date build than the default build provided by Apple. The lack of clipboard support alone is a good reason to choose MacVim over default Vim.
- It's extremely easy to install: download, drag, drop, done.
- It comes with a CLI wrapper that allows you to:

  1. launch the GUI from your shell, `$ mvim filename`
  2. use MacVim's bundled CLI executable *in* your shell, `$ mvim -v filename`
- If you use Homebrew, it is fairly easy to install a bleeding edge build.

Wait! I think [I've already talked about all that...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892547/what-are-the-advantages-of-macvim-over-vim/5894021#5894021) Whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Vim 7.4 on Mac Os X Snow Leopard (10.6.8) and I never had issue with the mouse support using iTerm until yesterday, when all mouse functionalities suddenly stopped working.

My .vimrc already contained `set mouse=a` but I still could not use the mouse functionalities.

I found the solution to my problem here ["set mouse=a" in vim doesn't work in screen](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2005-04/msg00042.html), you need to add to your .vimrc the following line

```
set ttymouse=xterm2
```

This brought back all mouse functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

I am on OS X 10.8, and after adding `set mouse=a` in `~/.vimrc` and installing [MouseTerm](https://github.com/brodie/mouseterm) (after installing SIMBL 0.9.9), I could scroll with my mouse on vim in my terminal (using [TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/), by the way).