# shortcut of making vim windows/panels equally in height

Tags: vim

I was reading the byte of vim. Here is a problem that I encountered.

*I am using vim in macosx. (command line not GUI)*

In the book, **"Want to make the windows 'equal' in height again? press ctrl-w ="**
I have tried that, but it does not working. And, it made some sound (which I believe it indicates that there is an error)

In addition, when I have looked at the mac vim help page about window, I did found this command.
I tried it again---still does not work in the command line mode, **but it did works in GUI mode (MacVim)**

Does anyone have any ideas to solve that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does `ctrl-w +` and `ctrl-w -` work for you?

Comment: Perhaps some folks want to try `:vsp` (vertical split) and/or `:sp` (horizontal split), and then cycle between windows with `control-w w`. If this sounds like what you were looking for when you found this question, then have a look at [how to effectively work with multiple files in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/53714/664833).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You wouldn't happen to be pressing <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-=</kbd>, would you?

I tried <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> in Vim in a Terminal, and it worked.  <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-=</kbd> didn't work in the terminal, but it did in MacVim.