# copy a line/multiple-lines from vi editor to cmd line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vi, konsole

Is there a shortcut key to copy a line from vi editor and then paste it into a terminal.
Currently I select the text with mouse and then press crtl+shift+c (I'm using default settings of KDE) and then do ctrl+shift+v on the konsole. The problem with this option is when the line is long enough to wrap. In that case copy-paste inserts extra spaces which I have to fix after pasting on terminal.

This is very annoying specially when the line copied is very long and contains file names (typically commands used to invoke compiler).

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: [how to copy codes in vi to clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532878/how-to-copy-codes-in-vi-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can yank to the X clipboard by putting the contents in the `*` register.

To do this use `"*yy` on the line you want to yank. Then outside of vim you should be able to paste it.

Comment: So I have to press " and then * and then yy? I tried but not working for me.

Comment: when you do `vim --version | grep clipboard` do you see a `+clipboard` or a `-clipboard`

Comment: You might also need `+X11` and/or `+xterm_clipboard`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10104125/955926

Comment: Yes I think;  6:-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
19:-X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save

Comment: You might need to get compile a different version of vim. You need to have `+clipboard` for this to work. and potentially the other one Gary Fixler mentioned.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll try that. The vim I have is the default one.

Comment: Try using apt-get with either vim-gtk or vim-gnome packages I believe these should have all the options enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to a clipboard via X or screen or tmux, you can write the contents of the buffer to a temp file, then go to the terminal and invoke `$(cat temp-file)` or open an editor for the command line and read in the file.  Whatever shell you are using probably provides a mechanism for opening an editor on the command line.  In bash with vi-style readline keybindings you can type v to get a vi session.  If you shell does not provide that functionality, try a different shell.