# How to paste to Vim when using PuTTY

Tags: vim, putty, paste

I am using PuTTY to connect a remote host and editing via Vim. I meet a trouble when I try to paste something to Vim. That is, I copy something to the clipboard in my local host and want to paste it to the Vim on the remote host. How can I do that?

PS: I am using PuTTY! So, I open a Vim window via PuTTY. The very need is that I want to copy something in my local host and paste it to the Vim editor opened by PuTTY. That's all.

Comment: How exactly did you try to paste into [tag:vim]? Is this of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14225889/1945981

Comment: I want to paste something to a putty vim window

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Try with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or with middle click with a 3 button mouse.

Or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd>.

*Source*: https://superuser.com/questions/180043/paste-the-windows-clipboard-into-my-putty-session-using-only-the-keyboard

Comment: Shift + Ins can paste what in clipboard to the putty window. But, my need is to copy what in clipboard to the vim editor opened by putty.

Comment: you need to be in the edit mode, not the visual mode, try pressing i and then Shift + Ins

Answer (score 68):

You can insert text from your host’s clipboard by pressing the right mouse button (default setting) or by pressing <kbd>Shift + Ins</kbd>. Note that this has the same effect as entering every character manually. So if you are using auto indentation in vim, this will very likely screw up your code.

To fix that, you can do the following:

1. Before pasting into vim, enable paste mode by entering `:set paste`.
2. Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode. The status bar should say `-- INSERT (paste) --` now.
3. Press the *right mouse button* to paste in your stuff. The auto indentation of vim should not happen.

   If this puts you into the `-- (insert) VISUAL --` mode, exit out of it using <kbd>Esc</kbd> (putting you into the paste insert mode again), and try pasting it again while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> using your right mouse button.
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave insert mode, and disable paste mode using `:set nopaste` again.

You can change which mouse button is used to paste in PuTTY in the Window/Selection configuration page.

Comment: 3rd step goes into -- INSERT (visual) --

Comment: What is happening when vim goes into `-- (insert) VISUAL --`? Why does holding Shift allow you to paste?

Answer (score 48):

In [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) it appears that you have to:

1. <kbd>i</kbd> = to enter `-- INSERT --` mode
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-`right-mouse-click` = to paste

If you just `right-mouse-click` (i.e. without shift) then annoyingly all that happens is that the mode changes to `-- (insert) VISUAL --` i.e. it doesn't paste anything.

Comment: I found shift, right-mouse-click also works for newer versions of Vim (8.0) when accessing through a putty session from Windows.

Comment: Or you can revert to previous behavior of right click to paste by adding `set mouse-=a` to your .vimrc ([source](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1326))

Comment: This also works for the reverse problem, where Putty will not copy text from Vim with `left-mouse-drag`, but will with `Shift left-mouse-drag`

Comment: `Shift`-`right-mouse-click` works for me through PuTTY

Comment: Always worked without shift, hand no idea what's happening. Vim 8.1 requires `shift`+`right-click` and works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

To clarify the other answers, there are a couple ways to do this, depending on if Vim is running with mouse support. Lets assume its via some sort of terminal/Putty:

- When not using mouse in remote Vim, right clicking will paste from local clipboard via Putty into remote Vim.
- With mouse enabled in remote Vim, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> will paste from local clipboard via putty into remote vim.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> will paste from local clipboard via native/*nixish/xterm into remote vim.
- With mouse enabled in remote Vim, middle clicking will paste from remote clipboard into remote Vim.

Answer (score -1):

**Copy-paste between Windows and PuTTY：**

To copy from Windows and paste into PuTTY, highlight the text in Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, select the PuTTY window, and press the right mouse button to paste. To copy from PuTTY and paste into Windows, highlight the information in PuTTY and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in the Windows application to paste it.

**Copy-paste between two Vim sessions in separate PuTTY:**

Highlight the information in the source PuTTY, and then press the right mouse button in the target PuTTY to paste.