# How do I paste from PuTTY into Vim 8.0?

Tags: windows, vim, putty

### Scenario

From a Windows 10 Anniversary Update client ...

- Open a web browser, copy / paste some text from a website (eg. GitHub)
- Use PuTTY 0.67 to SSH to a Linux VM (eg. Ubuntu 16 Xenial Xerus)
- Open a file in Vim
- Hit `i` to change into Insert mode
- Right-click to paste the clipboard contents

### Issue

Unfortunately, when I right-click in the PuTTY session, rather than pasting clipboard contents, what's actually happening is that Vim is going from `INSERT` mode to `(insert) VISUAL` mode. I don't think I've ever seen anything like this before.

### Question

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can paste my Windows client clipboard into the SSH / Vim session?

[image]

Comment: Default settings have been changed. Read `:h defaults.vim` how to override those settings. (Basically you would need to create a .vimrc file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797615/how-to-paste-to-vim-when-using-putty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem by turning off mouse mode.

```
:set mouse=
```

Answer (score 31):

It appears that this issue is due to a change in defaults for VIM version 8.0 and higher.

Previous versions had mouse mode turned off (`mouse=`), but the new default is mouse mode turned on (`mouse=a`).

There are 3 ways to deal with this situation:

1. **Adapt to it**: With mouse mode turned on, the new way to paste is *shift-right-click* (at least in PuTTY)
2. **Change it**: You can turn off mouse mode for your current VIM session by typing `:set mouse=` and <enter>
3. **Revert it**: You can override the new defaults by calling VIM with the "C" switch (`vim -C {filename}`) and it will revert back to the Vi "compatible" settings for that session

Of course you can always add `set mouse=` to your .vimrc file to make it permanent.  But that doesn't work for me because I hop around on too many different systems.

Comment: I think part of the issue is the PuTTY defaults - it sets TERM=xterm, but if you set TERM=putty, right-mouse works as expected.

Comment: maybe you should shift+rightclick twice, and select paste in the right click menu .just click once doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem

1. You just need to change in the vmrc file 
   vim $HOME/.vimrc
2. set the following in the file
   set mouse-=a to .vimrc

It worked fine