# Copying to clipboard in vi

Tags: ubuntu, vim, copy, clipboard, vi

So I've looked through this question: [how to copy codes in vi to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532878/how-to-copy-codes-in-vi-to-clipboard/14225889#14225889)
and found that it is possible but requires the -xterm_clipboard to be +xterm_clipboard. Apparently the only way to resolve that issue is to find a different version of vim to use, which I am hoping to avoid. Are there any other ways to accomplish copying to the clipboard without switching to something different?

If it's relevant, I'm running Ubuntu dual-booted with windows.

I apologize if this is a stupid question, I'm still rather new to command line programming, and there's a lot of stuff to learn.

Comment: Looks to me like that answer addressed your question. You can manually select the text and middle click to paste.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a different version? Install gvim, it should come with that option compiled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

will replace your current Vim with one that's built with clipboard support without changing anything to your configuration files or the features you are getting used to.

Answer (score 1):

Select what you would like to copy to the clipboard. In the gif below I used `ggVG` to select the entire text of the file.

Now the text you want is selected. To get this into the special `*` register that Vim uses for the system clipboard you would type `"*y`.

If you combine those commands (`ggVG"*y`) it should yank the text of the entire file into the system clipboard (the * register). The (rather bad quality) gif below shows this command in Vim copying to the system clipboard and pasting into TextEdit.

[image]

Going the other way is also possible using the `*` register.

Copy something that you want. Load Vim and type `"*p`. This accesses the `*` register and puts (pastes) it using `p`. Here's a gif where I copy someting to the clipboard and then use `"*p` in Vim to paste it.

[image]