# yanking lines from one terminal to another

Tags: vim, yank

I have two Terminals with vim open, side by side. Each Terminal has a different file. I can yank and paste lines within one of these Terminals/files, but how do I paste the yanked lines from one Terminal/file into the other open Terminal/file?

Comment: You probably have your reasons for having two terminals with vim open, but have you considered running one instance of vim in one terminal with twice the width? You can open the second file as a buffer, side by side with the other file you are editing.

For a couple sources on how, see

buffers:
http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-buffers/

windows: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-windows/

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532878/how-to-copy-codes-in-vi-to-clipboard/14225889#14225889

Answer (score 3):

First, check if your Vim is built with clipboard support with:

```
:echo has('clipboard')
```

If you get a `0`, install a proper Vim (but you didn't tell us what system you are on so we can't tell you how).

If you get a `1`, use either `"+y` and `"+p` or `"*y` and `"*p` to yank and paste (again, we can't tell you which one without knowing more on your setup).

See `:help register`.

Comment: So I have a MacOSX (El Capitan), and I got a 0 when i did :echo has('clipboard')

Comment: 1. Download MacVim. 2. Put the bundled `mvim` somewhere in your `$PATH`. 3. Use `mvim -v` instead of `vim`. 4. Enjoy clipboard integration.

Comment: This will copy it to your clipboard. But then I have to press Ctrl + V in insert mode. I was hoping to yank and put directly across terminal tabs (but using the same program, vim).

Answer (score 1):

You can also write to your clipboard using pbcopy if you do not have clipboard support in vim. If you highlight what you want in Visual mode and then type `:w !pbcopy` it will write to the clipboard. The command will actually look like this in practice: `:'<,'>w !pbcopy` because of the selected text.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply **Ctrl+shift+c** your selection. Put yourself in **insertion** mode in your vim then **Ctrl+shift+v** and it should work.