# Quickly switching buffers in Vim normal mode

Tags: vim

Recently I found out that I'm ["using tabs incorrectly" in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers/103590#103590). I've been trying to just use buffers in Vim since, assisted through [MiniBufExplorer](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim/), but I find it painful because of how many keystrokes it takes to change buffers from normal mode. With tabs, I can just do <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to hop back and forth between tabs in normal mode, and I can also do <kbd>NUMBER</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to go to a specific tab.

With buffers, I either have to enter command mode with `:bn`, `:bp`, or with MiniBufExplorer, use <kbd>Ctrl + k</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Up</kbd> to hop up to the buffer window, scroll left or right with <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the buffer I want. Or I can do something involving a leader sequence, but it always requires removing multiple fingers away from home row. That's a real pain.

How can I get something equivalent switching tabs in normal mode to switch buffers in normal mode, so I can do something like <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> for `:bn`/`:bp` and <kbd>NUMBER</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> for `:buf NUMBER`?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Add this to your `.vimrc`

```
map gn :bnext<cr>
map gp :bprevious<cr>
map gd :bdelete<cr>  

" I personally use <leader> 
map <leader>n :bnext<cr>
map <leader>p :bprevious<cr>
map <leader>d :bdelete<cr>
```

Note that you are remapping `gp` and `gd`, but maybe you don't care about that (`:help gp`, `:help gd`).

For more information on how to map key strokes see `:help map-overview` and `:help map.txt`.

Btw, I personally use `<leader>` instead of `g` in the mapping.  My `<leader>` is set to `;`. This puts my `<leader>` key on the home row which makes me willing to map all kinds of stuff using `<leader>`.  `:help mapleader` if you want to change your `<leader>` key.

Comment: Good suggestion on using `<leader>`. Originally I didn't like this because `\ ` is the original leader and was not easy to reach, but of course, the right thing to do was redefine the leader to be something close to home-row, in my case `,`, which is easier than `;` for Dvorak layout.

Comment: this would possibly affect gn (select next instance of last search), which some might use with some macros and repeats.

Comment: Having `<leader>d` as a mapping to `:bd` I find to be more annoying than worth it. It's quite easy to type `<leader>d` by accident and then you have to go and re-open your file again. I find this risk more annoying than typing `:bd` each time. But then typically I almost never delete the buffer, I just leave all the buffers open/hidden and then run `:%bd` to delete them all once I'm done on a certain piece of work. It's one of the nice things of Vim that you don't really have to care about how many buffers you have open.

Answer (score 60):

The way I usually switch between buffers is to use the `:buffer` command with the built-in autocompletion, e.g. `:b prof<Tab>` to switch to `folder/path/LoginProfileFactory.php`.

You can just start typing any part of the file name of the buffer you need, which is nice.

Less often, I actually remember the numbers of the buffers I want and I use something like `:b 3` or `:3b`.
I see you mention you don't like `:buf 3` though, so [Rumple Stiltskin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559029/quickly-switching-buffers-in-vim-normal-mode/5562875#5562875) has an alternative to the `:3b` style that you may prefer.

Comment: You don't even have to start typing any part of the file, just type `:b <Tab>` (N.B. don't forget to add a space) and it will start cycling though the buffers you have open. Helpful if you can't even remember the filenames

Comment: I find including `lastused` in my `wildmode` (I use `set wildmenu wildmode=lastused:full`) is very convenient as it cycles through matches in most recently used order, making it easy to jump back to a recent buffer.

Answer (score 41):

[`{count}CTRL-^`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#CTRL-%5E) switches to the `count` numbered buffer.

Comment: So remember every buffer ID? do `:buffers` before this or see my answer...

Comment: Use the MiniBufExplorer plugin to see the numbers and this to switch between them

Answer (score 41):

I have the following lines in .vimrc:

```
nnoremap  <silent>   <tab>  :if &modifiable && !&readonly && &modified <CR> :write<CR> :endif<CR>:bnext<CR>
nnoremap  <silent> <s-tab>  :if &modifiable && !&readonly && &modified <CR> :write<CR> :endif<CR>:bprevious<CR>
```

Now a Tab let you go to the next buffer and a Shift-Tab to the previous.

Comment: Very nice. Easily the best solution. tab is after all a navigation key. how about ctl-sh-tab and ctl-tab for tabs?

Comment: @HörmannHH Unfortunately, some shortcuts cannot be mapped in Vim, which is the case of <C-Tab>.

Comment: this is great. I'm stealing it

Comment: If you have `:set hidden` do you need the values of the modifiable, readonly, modified?

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Comment: ancient answer by now, but small request - maybe better to quickly explain the benefit of adding the modifiable, readonly and modified terms instead of a simple map/remap/inoremap.

Answer (score 28):

This is based on [Nick Knowlson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5571207/327074), but I wanted to expand on my comment there ...

> Type `:b <Tab>` (note the space), then cycle through the open buffers with <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>.

... which gets us closer to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in all the other editors and browsers I use.

It's actually even better in some ways, you can then go backwards and forwards with <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> arrows. It avoids the thumb + finger fu to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go backwards through the tabs in editors and browsers.

N.B. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> just does the same as <kbd>Tab</kbd>

This is then actually something like <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows 10, where once you first open up the window and you can then move around using the arrow keys.

**Edit**: I have two further tricks that I picked up for using buffers:

1. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44647932/327074) I have this in my `.vimrc`:

   ```
   nnoremap <leader>bb :buffers<cr>:b<space>
   ```

   it opens the `:ls` / `:buffers` command and pre-types the `:b` so that you just have to type the buffer number as you'll see a list with all the buffers and their numbers.
2. I also have

   ```
   nnoremap <leader><tab> :b#<cr>
   ```

   which toggles between the current and most recently used buffers, it's a bit like doing `cd -` when switching back and forth between directories

Answer (score 18):

I use the plugin [unimpaired.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590)

it defines mappings `[b` and `]b` that jump to the previous and next buffer in the list.

For jumping for a specific buffer the best option I know is the one you mentioned: `:b<number>`

If you go into another buffer you can came back quickly by typing `<c-^>`

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on [Rumple Stiltskin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559029/quickly-switching-buffers-in-vim-normal-mode/5562875#5562875)'s answer, if you know that the file you want to get to is in buffer `4`, for example, you can get there quickly with

```
4Ctrl-^
```

On my UK keyboard, I can actually do `4Ctrl-6`, as explained in

```
:help CTRL-^
```

By the way, you can see the buffer numbers with

```
:buffers
```

or

```
:ls
```

Answer (score 7):

I use [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890): I hit `<leader>b` to open a list of buffers then a couple of letters from the name of the buffer I want to open then `enter`. Easy.

But, you are not "using tabs incorrectly", you are using tabs the way you want. If it worked for you why go through the pain of unlearning your way to learn "the right way"?

Comment: LustyExplorer looks very neat and may be what I finally settle on. There's a very good video demo at http://lococast.net/archives/185 around 7 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I use F9 and F10 to move between the previous/next buffer with this mapping:

```
map <F9> :bprevious<CR>
map <F10> :bnext<CR>
```

For me this is the fastest way to switch buffers.

Answer (score 4):

[fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) is another fast way to changes buffers using fuzzy matching. This plug-in ships with the default command:

```
:Buffers
```

which opens the list of all open buffers similar to :ls but a buffer can be (fuzzy) searched and selected. 
Opening the buffer in the current window is through enter, but can can also be opened in a new split (h or v) or tab using ^X ^V or ^T respectively.

Noteworthy is also:

```
:Lines
```

Which allows to search through the content of all open buffers. This can be handy if you forget the name of a buffer but you know what it should contain.

Comment: FZF is generally great and I always use it when opening a file that isn't in the buffers. I have this in my `.vimrc`: `nnoremap <leader>bb :buffers<cr>:b<space>` it opens the `:ls` / `:buffers` command and pre-types the `:b ` so that you just have to type the buffer number. This is normally enough for me. I also find that the `:buffers` command appears instantly where as there is a frustrating delay when opening `:Buffers` (at least in GVim on Windows which is where I'm using Vim most).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
" `<leader><Tab>` - next buffer;
nnoremap  <silent> <leader><Tab>    :bnext<CR> 

" `<leader><S-Tab>` - previous buffer;
nnoremap  <silent> <leader><S-Tab>  :bprevious<CR>

" `_bufferNumber_ + <Tab>` - go exact the buffer number;
nnoremap  <silent> <Tab>            <C-^>
```

By the way, I use 'buftabline' plugin and set `let g:buftabline_numbers = 1` to spread my buffer on the tabline.

[image: buftabline]

Answer (score 2):

I make it easier for myself:
In `.vimrc` :

```
nnoremap <leader>bf :buffers<CR>:buffer "<- Last spaces is necessary
```

For example, in normal mode, say your leader key is `\`(default it is), type `\bf`, then you have a list of opened buffers, type number of buffer you want and hit enter key.
NOTE: remember that last spaces   not necessary at all if you wich type it after :D

Jut like that ;)

[image: switching buffers in vim with above nnoremap]

More detail:

`<C-O>` Navigate backward

`<C-I>` Navigate forward

So there is no need extra remapping, otherwise you remapped them.

Answer (score 1):

I think [bufexplorer](https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer)  is a nice plugin to use. <kbd>`<leader>`</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> brings up an interactive buffer explorer that lists all open buffers. You could quickly move through the list and <kbd>Enter</kbd> puts you in the selected buffer. Unlike `LustyExplorer` It has no dependency to ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer navigating between buffers similarly to how I'm navigating between window panes: `<alt-h>` and `<alt-l>`. This is to straightforward to set on Mac because `<alt>/<option>` key binds are bounded to specific characters.

```
" Buffer navigation
map ˙ :bp<cr>
map ¬ :bn<cr>
map § <c-^>
```

Here is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24047539/4950238) that shows how you can see characters maped to `<alt-..>` combinations