# How to pass the result of find to vim's argadd command

Tags: file, vim, find

I previously found out, [and posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436685/654789), about how to load multiple buffers using `:argadd` instead of `:badd`. However, I would further like to add all files of all subdirectories matching a certain pattern. My current attempt looks like so:

```
:argadd !find . -name *.js -type f
```

But that adds

```
 51      "!find"                        line 1
 52      "~/Documents/neuro-sim/website/3.0" line 1
 53      "-name"                        line 1
 54      "*.js"                         line 1
 55      "-type"                        line 1
 56      "f"                            line 1
```

to the buffer. What modification do I have to make to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But why don't you do it with

```
:args **/*.js
```

(Yeah, I know you can't filter for files this way...)

HTH

Comment: will that recursively go through every subdirectory? Can I do `:args /home/user/*.js`?

Comment: @puk: no, but `:args **/*.js` will. See `:help wildcards`

Comment: Can you please put the `**/*.js` in the answer then I will accept this.

Comment: Thanks @Benoit, I wanted to write that :-)

Comment: I have too much e-courtesy. I should have edited it myself and pocketed the 2 rep points.

Answer (score 0):

You need backticks "`" to evaluate the find and plug them into args. I agree it does seem strange to not use "!" but I think that is for handling stream buffers not args...

```
:arga `find . -name '*glob_pattern*'`
```