# Find file in vim, switch to next file without saving current file

Tags: vim

Vim newbie here.
I use :find command to open a file and make some changes.
Suppose I want to open another file without saving the current changes, then how should I do it.
What is the best way to list all open files and quickly open them again for editing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the lines `set hidden` (load files without saving current file) and `set wildmenu` (useful command line tab-completion) to your `.vimrc`. Then to start editing a file in a new buffer you can do `:edit yourFile.txt`. Unlike `:find <tab>` command,  `:edit <tab>` (or :`e <tab>` for short) will only display files in current directory. Alternatively you can download a plugin like [`CtrlP`](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) dedicated to find/load files quickly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to effectively work with multiple files in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664/how-to-effectively-work-with-multiple-files-in-vim)

Answer (score 1):

```
:e! filename
```

will allow you to open a named file in a new buffer (note the exclamation mark overrides the warning re. an unsaved file).

```
CTRL-W + cursor
```

will move between visible buffers and does not enforce the saving of your file as you navigate.

```
:buffers
```

will list your open buffers and allow you to navigate to each one (albeit with some cryptic flags indicating which buffers are visible/hidden/amended etc.)

```
:help buffers
```

will tell you about all the buffer-related features.

```
:help :wincmd
```

will tell you all about windows navigations

See also the [VIM buffer FAQ](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ)

Comment: :e! command only search in the cwd for files while :find recursively search in the cwd for files.
is there a way to open file in buffer using find command.
also CTRL-W + cursor command doesn't seems to work.
Thanks.